# php - Unable to update an image from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would want to edit the image. But instead of updating the image, my code, for some reason is adding the data into the table instead of updating the values. Where am I making mistakes? I have also ran the query as a sql command and it is perfectly working there, but for some reason, here it is appending the values to the table.

Here's my db named artist_list:
[image: link]

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
//Checking User Logged or Not
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
 header('location:index.php');
}
//Restrict User or admin to Access moderator.php page
if($_SESSION['user']['role'] !='sadmin' && $_SESSION['user']['role']!='admin_mum'){
 //header('location:admin_pun.php');
    echo"YOU DO NOT HAVE PEMISSION.";
    exit;
}
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "organisation");
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {      
        $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `artist_list` SET `name`= ? , `bio`= ? , `image`= ? WHERE id= ?");
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $bio = $_POST['bio'];
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $target = "../images/".basename($image);
        $sql->bind_param("sssi",$name,$bio,$image,$_GET["id"]); 
        if($sql->execute()) {
            $success_message = "Edited Successfully";
        } else {
            $error_message = "Problem in Editing Record";
        }

    }
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `artist_list` WHERE id=?");
    $sql->bind_param("i",$_GET["id"]);          
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<title>employee edit </title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><div><img src="#" style="vertical-align: top;"></div></center>
<?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
<div class="success message"><?php echo $success_message; ?></div>
<?php } if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
<div class="error message"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<a href="about-admin_mum.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Back To List</a>
    <form method="POST" action="artist_list-mumbai.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-success" style="margin : 20px;" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
    <p style="margin-left : 20px;">name:</p><input type="text" name="name" style="margin-left : 20px;" value="<?php echo $row["name"]?>"><br><br>
    <p style="margin-left: 20px;">Bio:</p><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="bio" style="margin-left : 20px;"><?php echo $row["bio"]?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-success" style="margin : 20px;">UPLOAD</button>
    </div>
    </form>

<footer><img src="#"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have posted the proper controller? There is no possibility that new rows are inserted with this code

Comment: @NicoHaase Could you elaborate?

Comment: If new rows are inserted, a `INSERT` query is run. Your code does not contain such a query. So I assume that the posted code is not the executed code - but you can check that on your own through adding some debugging. Have you even tried that?

Comment: See, this is my table before editing.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIv4k.png
When I decided to change the image, then a new row is being created : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obm8O.png

Comment: Why is this happening. I have no idea. When I try to run it in sql query, it is perfectly updating the row

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this?

Comment: @NicoHaase Tried changing the query

Comment: Which one? Is the given code even executed? If yes, can you dump the **exact executed query** and run that on your own?

Comment: A side point: This is not secure: `if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
 header('location:index.php');
}`. You need to write `if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
 header('location:index.php'); die();
}` otherwise even though you redirected, PHP will still continue to execute the rest of this script in the background. This could leak data and/or cause unauthenticated actions to take place.

Comment: Another side point: The `<center>` tag is obsolete - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center. You should be using CSS instead to achieve this effect.

Comment: Lastly: **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes, so this just leaves an unnecessary open door for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even do this is a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Anyway Nico is right, there is no way this code could ever insert any rows. In terms of debugging, you mention you "changed the query"...this doesn't tell us much...changed it to what? To demonstrate what? What was the result?

Comment: @ADyson Okay, I will take your suggestions into account.

Comment: @ADyson Looking at these 2 images and the code, do you have any idea why is the new image is being uploaded as a new row?
Before :  i.stack.imgur.com/DIv4k.png 
After :  i.stack.imgur.com/Obm8O.png

Comment: No, I don't, that's mine and Nico's point. Nothing in the code you've shown would lead to that. To add a new row it needs to use an `INSERT` query, not an `UPDATE` Are you sure that's all your code? Try tracing the execution of the PHP code - even just inserting some "echo" statements at different points, or logging something to disk, so you can see where the flow goes. See if you get to the point you expected, or not.

Comment: @ADyson EXACTLY. I am confused.
Okay, I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I seem to have found a solution. Removing "gallery-mumbai.php" from the action seems to have solved the problem. I have no idea why my code has started working though!

```
<?php
session_start();
//Checking User Logged or Not
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
 header('location:index.php');
}
//Restrict User or admin to Access moderator.php page
if($_SESSION['user']['role'] !='sadmin' && $_SESSION['user']['role']!='admin_mum'){
 //header('location:admin_pun.php');
    echo"YOU DO NOT HAVE PEMISSION.";
    exit;
}
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "organisation");
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {      
        $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `images` SET `images`= ? WHERE id= ?");
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $target = "../images/".basename($image);
        $sql->bind_param("si",$image,$_GET["id"]);  
        if($sql->execute()) {
            $success_message = "Edited Successfully";
        } else {
            $error_message = "Problem in Editing Record";
        }

    }
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE id=?");
    $sql->bind_param("i",$_GET["id"]);          
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<title>employee edit </title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><div><img src="http://10.31.3.3/Nimg/ITHeader2.png" style="vertical-align: top;"></div></center>
<?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
<div class="success message"><?php echo $success_message; ?></div>
<?php } if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
<div class="error message"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<a href="about-admin_mum.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Back To List</a>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> /* Removing "gallery-mumbai.php" from action seems to have solved my problem. */
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-success" style="margin : 20px;" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-success" style="margin : 20px;">UPLOAD</button>
    </div>
    </form>

<footer><img src="http://10.31.3.3/Nimg/Footer1.png"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: presumably that action was telling it to post back to the wrong place. You never made clear what the name of the page you were displaying was?